# React-Native Map() data structure?

Tags: react-native

Does react-native not support javascript's Map()? The following code is returning an empty object:

```
  const x = new Map()
  x.set(1, 'a')
  x.set(2, 'b')
  console.log(x)
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need `Map()`?

Comment: Yes, I need an easy way to refer to objects within a collection. Hashmap is my go to when I do this.

Comment: Would this suffice?
`const x = {}; x[1] = 'a'; x[2] = 'b';`

Comment: Yes! Thank you.

Comment: `Map` is supported by React Native, as is `Set`.

Comment: If it's supported then how come I was getting back an empty object with such a basic example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-native only supports a subset of Javascript functionality [as listed here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment). This may explain the reason for the unexpected behaviour.

To achieve this what you're requiring in your react-native app, you could use an object to map key/value pairs in a similar way like so:

```
const x = {}; 
x[1] = 'a'; 
x[2] = 'b';
console.log(x);
```

Comment: That is strange because Map is used in the documentation for FlatList https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist